# Why can $(x,y)$ coordinates be defined as $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ for the unit circle?

Tags: trigonometry, intuition

I am having a hard time understanding that how/why can we define $(x,y)$ as $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta$. I googled and found out that we can do that because for $\theta\geq\frac\pi2$, a triangle can be contructed in all cases, so we can always get a $\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$ relationship. But what **I** cannot understand is that: 
Suppose $\theta$ is in the second quadrant. So the triangle we will contruct will have a $\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$ relationship for $180-\theta$ not $\theta$. So how can we define it like that? 
I know it seems a bit crazy but lets put it like this. *$\sin\theta$ is opposite upon hypotenuse. But suppose the angle is obtuse, then how will we get this relationship?*

Comment: What is your definition of cosine and sine? It is somewhat popular to _define_ them as the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of appropriate points on the unit circle, since this immediately gives the right behavior for angles outside the interval fro 0° to 90°.

Comment: That is what my question is. **My definition:** $\sin\theta$ is opposite upon hypotenuse. So how can we define it for all angles {obtuse, right, reflex}

Comment: How do we know what is the *right behaviour*?

Comment: I was trying to search for an illustration of why the unit circle definition agrees with SOH CAH TOA for angles between $0$ and $\pi/2$. I would be surprised if no one has given such an illustration on math stackexchange before - I'm guessing my search capabilities just suck - but if that really is the case, someone should create an illustrated answer here.

Comment: It is available on Wikipedia.  But it doesnt answer the **why** part.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I know that a triangle can me made in everycase but this makes it a bit circular. We define sinx as opposite upon hypotenuse. Then we deduce that $\sin (\pi-x)=\sin x$ because of the hypotenuse- side relationship in the triangle.

Comment: Maybe that's why there aren't any illustrations here. I'm not sure what you mean by your deduction; $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin x$ comes from the fact that you reflect across the $y$-axis in the unit circle, which doesn't affect the $y$-coordinate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When one first meets the trigonometric functions, they are best interpreted as ratios of different sides of a right triangle. Later, one might ask the question: what is the sine of 91°, for example? There is a German article on Wikipedia: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanenzprinzip. I don't know whether a similar term exists in English, but it is a principle followed in generalizations. It is also applied in the unit circle-definition of the trigonometric functions. When the angle is between 0 and 90°, we get back the previous definitions. It also leads to the polar coordinate system, where the minus sign is never negligible, and the sine-cosine interpretation should give back the x-y components.

Another way to approach: how would **you** extend the definitions of sine and cosine to any real angle?

Nonetheless, it might worth trying different definitions and see their implications.

The further generalization is the function itself: one can easily talk about the sine, cosine, etc. functions without any reference to the unit circle: their representation as Taylor-series, and finally (?) the Euler-form, relating the exponential to the trigonometric function. This generalization seems to be a very effective one.

(If you don't know German or Hungarian: the linked "Permanenzprinzip" means the principle that a generalization should be one that has as many similarities with the original definitions as possible. The first instance one encounters is the idea of number systems and algebraic operations.)

Comment: "Permanenzprinzip" sounds like a really good word. I feel like a lot of English-speaking math students transitioning from high school to university would be much less confused if they had this word to give a name to the concept.

Answer (score 5):

The usual (most general and straightforward) **geometric** definition of the sine and cosine is:

> $(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$ are the coordinates of the point on the unit circle whose arc distance from $(1,0)$ measured counterclockwise along the circle itself, is $\theta$.

This immediately gives the right value for *all* $\theta$ -- where "right" means, among a lot of other things, that it is the only choice that makes $\sin$ and $\cos$ analytic everywhere *and* agrees with the right-triangle definition you seem to prefer for angles between $0$ and $\pi/2$.

In **analysis** different definitions are often preferred, usually the power series:

> $$ \cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} - \cdots + (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!} + \cdots \\
> \sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120} - \cdots + (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} + \cdots $$

which have the advantage that they're easy to generalize to complex arguments. But it then takes a fair amount of proofwork to show that these series converge for every $x$, and that these definitions agree with the geometric ones.

Comment: So this is a type of convention, a defintion? So this is **not** circular.?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal: Yes it's a definition. Definitions are a kind of conventions, namely conventions about what we take certain words and symbols to mean.